# Unable to detect string when term is located at multiple locations

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a dataset where I want to detect terms that do not have specific terms before them. The problem is that this term can occur multiple times in the field. I have tried these two methods. But in each, I have not over detect or under detect.

```
library(stringr)
x <- "In the first round the car had no flat tyre. In the secound round there was a flat"
str_detect(x,"((?i)(?<!no )flat) & ((?i)(?<!not )flat)")
```

This returns a `FLASE` but we want it to be `TRUE`. Changing to `|` will detect the term even when it shouldn't be:

```
x <- "In the first round the car had no flat tyre."
str_detect(x,"((?i)(?<!no )flat) | ((?i)(?<!not )flat)")
```

This returns `TRUE` while we want `FALSE`.

How do I ensure that I am able to detect the term correctly.

**Edit 1:**
I want to detect the term *flat*, that is not preceded any one of these terms: *no* or *not* or *otherterm*.

Comment: The term you want to detect is `"flat"`? And if it is, what are the terms you don't want before them?

Comment: `str_detect(x,"((?i)(?<!no )flat) & ((?i)(?<!not )flat)")` will always return `FALSE`**unless** you have literal `&`in the string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine two look behind to test if there is neither *no* nor *not* before *flat*.

```
x <- "In the first round the car had no flat tyre. In the secound round there was a flat"
grepl("(?i)(?<!no )(?<!not )flat", x, perl=TRUE)
#[1] TRUE

x <- "In the first round the car had no flat tyre."
grepl("(?i)(?<!no )(?<!not )flat", x, perl=TRUE)
#[1] FALSE
```

Or using `stringr::str_detect`:

```
stringr::str_detect(x, "(?i)(?<!no )(?<!not )flat")
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_detect`, just as `grepl`, simply tests whether a pattern is **contained** in a string. So if you have the (one) string "no flat tyre a flat tyre" but want to test whether the string contains instances of "tyre" that are **not** preceded by "flat" then running `str_detect` or `grepl` won't be useful. More useful for your purpose, if that purpose is to check whether there are instances of "flat" **not** preceded by, say, "flat" would be using, for example, `str_extract`, like so:

```
str_extract(x,"(?i)(?<!not? )flat")
[1] "flat"
```

This asserts that the substring "flat" is only to be extracted if it is not preceded by "no" or "not" followed by whitespace.

The operation does return one `flat`, indicating that the string does contain the pattern you're actually looking for.

Data:

```
x <- "In the first round the car had no flat tyre. In the secound round there was a flat"
```

Comment: This will only detect the term if they have similar spellings (no/not). But if the term is completely different, then this doesn't work. EG: detect term _Ventilation_ that is not preceded by _mask_ or _invasive_.